# Update value on sessionStorage object

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I have an object already on sessionStorage coded with:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('queryData', JSON.stringify(data));
let data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('queryData'));
```

So far so good, My goal is however to be able to update specific values on that object so they are accessible across pages after the update.

```
{Obj: [,…]}
   Ojb: [,…]
     0: {…}
      dateOfBirth: "12331"
      firstName: "Manue"
```

Something like :

```
sessionStorage.setItem('queryData', update(firstName: "John"));
```

How to update specific values within a pre-defined localSession object?

Comment: Use `JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('queryData'))` change it and set it again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let data = {firstName:'john', lastName:'doe'};
sessionStorage.setItem('queryData', JSON.stringify(data));

function update(value){
    let prevData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('queryData'));
    Object.keys(value).forEach(function(val, key){
         prevData[val] = value[val];
    })
    sessionStorage.setItem('queryData', JSON.stringify(prevData));
}

update({firstName: "new Name"})
```